# I need to remotely connect to my docker swarm to create a service from my ci / cd pipeline using a shell script

Tags: docker, devops, docker-swarm, ssh-tunnel, github-actions

I am using docker for aws, I have a cluster and I need to create a service from a github actions pipeline

```
  ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "${SSH_KEY_PATH}" "${DOCKER_REMOTE_HOST}" "\"${COMMNAD}\""
```

Comment: All you have shown in your question is an `ssh` command. Show the work that you have done, any errors that you have and what help you need.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added a comment

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot ...., now I have this error I have tried to do this

```
time="2019-11-08T15:07:50Z" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-l docker ****.****.compute.amazonaws.com -- docker system dial-stdio]"
time="2019-11-08T15:07:50Z" level=debug msg="commandconn (ssh):Host key verification failed.\r\n"
```

doing something like that

```
    SSH_HOST=${DOCKER_REMOTE_HOST#"ssh://"}
    SSH_HOST=${SSH_HOST#*@}

    echo "Registering SSH keys..."

    # Save private key to a file and register it with the agent.
    mkdir -p "$HOME/.ssh"
    printf '%s' "$INPUT_DOCKER_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >"$HOME/.ssh/docker"
    chmod 600 "$HOME/.ssh/docker"
    eval $(ssh-agent)
    ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/docker"

    # eval $(ssh-agent)
    # ssh-add "${SSH_KEY_PATH}"
    # Add public key to known hosts.
    printf '%s %s\n' "$SSH_HOST" "$INPUT_DOCKER_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" >>/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
    printf '%s %s\n' "$SSH_HOST" "$INPUT_DOCKER_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

```
docker --log-level debug --host "$DOCKER_REMOTE_HOST" service create -d -q my-image
```

Using openssh-client to connect by ssh to my amazon EC2 and create a service in my docker swarm

Comment: Is this an answer, or information that should have been in the question?